# Creating a 2 axis graph with a 3rd axis as a color chart

Tags: plotly

new here to this forum
I have a task of making a graph with 3 axis - but not a 3D one.
One axis for X, one axis for Y and another color chart for temperature. This is supposed to be a bar chart, that has different color for every temperature.
Also, I would like the input to be Lists of data.

An example:

[click here for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRpGD.png)

But of course, I need different parameters and data.
The code I found for the example is this:

```
"
import plotly.express as px
data = px.data.gapminder()

data_canada = data[data.country == ‘Canada’]
fig = px.bar(data_canada, x=‘year’, y=‘pop’,
hover_data=[‘lifeExp’, ‘gdpPercap’], color=‘lifeExp’,
labels={‘pop’:‘population of Canada’}, height=400)
fig.show()
"
```

which I don’t know how to match for my lists of data.
My goal is to receive 3 lists with points in the graph, one for X, one for Y, and one for matching the color to the temperature.

Thanks in advance,
Moshe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

#Example Data Set

x = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
y = [2,4,6,8,10,12]
z = [10,20,60,20,10,40]


fig = go.Figure([go.Bar(x=x,
                        y=y,
                        marker=dict(color=z,colorscale='sunset')
                       )
                 ]
                )


fig.update_layout(width=400,height=400)

fig.show()
```

[image: graph]

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot!
How do I also add a little chart that says what is the value of every color ?

Comment: Do you mean legend ?

Comment: yeah. I want a scale on the side to match a number (the temperature) for every color. Is that done by "legend"?